# how to display images horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align images horizontally but they look vertical. Where is my fault?

```html
 <div class="col-1 text-right pt-4">
                    <div class="row d-block">
                            <a href="" target="_blank">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/yyy.svg') }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <a href=""   target="_blank">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/yyy.svg') }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            </a> 
                            <a href=""   target="_blank">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/xxx.svg') }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            </a> 
                            <a href=""   target="_blank">
                                <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/xxx.svg') }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            </a> 
                    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: problem is here - <div class="row d-block">. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: I've always wondered where people learn that they can do rows without columns, or columns without a parent row.

Answer (score 0):

You add class "d-block" to the parent of links>images and this is a problem. In bootstrap .row = display: flex(default render elements in row).

Comment: ı did it but widths of <a> tags are 0 now.

Comment: add d-block class to <a>  and col-4 if you want 3 icons  taken all row width together.